# What is convergence in w? Help me please.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I have an exercise that referrer to convergence in "$w$", what does that mean? Can you help me with that? The exercise say that:

Suppose $x_{n} \stackrel{w}{\longrightarrow} x$ and $y_{n} \stackrel{w}{\longrightarrow} y$ in a Hilbert space $H$ and $\alpha_{n} \stackrel{w}{\longrightarrow}\alpha$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Prove or disprove that $x_{n}+y_{n} \stackrel{w}{\longrightarrow} x+y$.

Comment: $\stackrel w\to$ stands for convergence in the weak topology, sometimes also indicated with $\rightharpoonup$, i.e. that $\phi(x_n)\to \phi(x)$ for all continuous functionals $\phi\in H^*$ (the dual of $H$).

Comment: Thank you so much.